# ElasticSearch - JavaApi searching not happening without (*) in my input query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am fetching documents from elastic search using java api, i have the following `code` in my elastic search documents and am trying to search it with the following pattern.

`code : MS-VMA1615-0D`

```
Input : *VMA1615-0*     -- Am getting the results (MS-VMA1615-0D).
Input : MS-VMA1615-0D   -- Am getting the results (MS-VMA1615-0D).
Input : *VMA1615-0      -- Am getting the results (MS-VMA1615-0D).
Input : *VMA*-0*        -- Am getting the results (MS-VMA1615-0D).
```

But, if i give input like below, am not getting results.

```
Input : VMA1615         -- Am not getting the results.
```

Am expecting to return the code `MS-VMA1615-0D`

Please find my below java code that am using

```
private final String INDEX = "products";
private final String TYPE = "doc";
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
    searchRequest.types(TYPE);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    QueryStringQueryBuilder qsQueryBuilder = new QueryStringQueryBuilder(code); 

    qsQueryBuilder.defaultField("code");
    searchSourceBuilder.query(qsQueryBuilder);

    searchSourceBuilder.size(50);
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
         searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance().search(searchRequest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    Item item = null;
    SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
```

Please find my mapping details :

```
PUT products
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "custom_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "char_filter": [
        "html_strip"
      ],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    }
   }
  }
},
"mappings": {
"doc": {
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
       }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you're looking for you might have to change the tokenizer you're using. Currently you are using **whitespace** tokenizer which must be replaced with **pattern** tokenizer. 
So your new mapping should look like the below one:

```
PUT products
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "custom_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "pattern",
      "char_filter": [
        "html_strip"
      ],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    }
   }
  }
},
"mappings": {
"doc": {
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

So after changing your mapping a query to **VMA1615** will return **MS-VMA1615-0D**.

This works as it tokenize the string "MS-VMA1615-0D" into "MS", "VMA1615" & "0D". So, whenever in your query you have any of them it will give you the result.

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "pattern",
  "text": "MS-VMA1615-0D"
}
```

will return:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "MS",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "VMA1615",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "0D",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**Based on your comment:**

> It is not how elasticsearch works. Elasticsearch stores the terms and
>   their corresponding documents in an inverted index data structure and
>   by default the terms produced by a full text search is based on
>   white-spaces, i.e. a text "Hi there I am a technocrat" would split up
>   as ["Hi", "there", "I", "am", "a", "technocrat"]. So this implies that
>   the terms which gets stored depends on how it is tokenized. After
>   indexing when you query let's say in the above example if I query for
>   "technocrat", I will get the result as the inverted index has that
>   term associated with my document. So in your case "VMA" is not stored as a term.

To do that use the below mapping:

```
PUT products
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "custom_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "my_pattern_tokenizer",
      "char_filter": [
        "html_strip"
      ],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    }
   },
   "tokenizer": {
     "my_pattern_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "-|\\d"
        }
   }
  }
},
"mappings": {
"doc": {
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

So to check:

```
POST products/_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "my_pattern_tokenizer",
  "text": "MS-VMA1615-0D"
}
```

will produce:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "MS",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "VMA",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "D",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This pattern is not working if am searching for `VMA`. Is that possible to make it searchable for only `VMA`...?

Comment: Yes it is possible if you're not worried about the numbers after VMA i.e. "1616" ?

Comment: If you're not worried about the digits then I can change my answer. Let me know !

Comment: Yes Please., its like, permutation and combination. Am giving input as `VMA` also, and am expecting it should return something related to my input, because it is available in Elastic Search. I think it make sense.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thankyou soo much for your detailed explaination., its really helpful. Am trying to search character by character instead of term (word). I have create a new question for the same.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222954/elasticsearch-javaapi-searching-by-each-character-instead-of-term-word