# ElasticSearch - JavaApi searching by each character instead of term (word)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am fetching documents from elastic search using java api, i have the following `code` in my elastic search documents and am trying to search it with the following pattern.

`code : MS-VMA1615-0D`

```
Input : MS-VMA1615-0D   -- Am getting the results (MS-VMA1615-0D).
Input : VMA1615         -- Am getting the results (MS-VMA1615-0D) .
Input : VMA             -- Am getting the results (MS-VMA1615-0D) .
```

But, if i give input like below, am not getting results.

```
Input : V       -- Am not getting the results.
INPUT : MS      -- Am not getting the results.
INPUT : -V      -- Am not getting the results.
INPUT : 615     -- Am not getting the results.
```

Am expecting to return the code `MS-VMA1615-0D`. In simple, am trying to search character by character instead of term (word).

It should not return the code `MS-VMA1615-0D` for the following cases, Because its not matching with my code.

```
Input : VK      -- should not return the results.
INPUT : MS3     -- should not return the results.
```

Please find my below java code that am using

```
private final String INDEX = "products";
private final String TYPE = "doc";
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
    searchRequest.types(TYPE);
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    QueryStringQueryBuilder qsQueryBuilder = new QueryStringQueryBuilder(code); 

    qsQueryBuilder.defaultField("code");
    searchSourceBuilder.query(qsQueryBuilder);

    searchSourceBuilder.size(50);
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
         searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance().search(searchRequest);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    Item item = null;
    SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
```

Please find my mapping details :

```
PUT products
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "custom_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "my_pattern_tokenizer",
      "char_filter": [
        "html_strip"
      ],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    }
   },
   "tokenizer": {
     "my_pattern_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "-|\\d"
        }
   }
  }
},
"mappings": {
"doc": {
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

After Update with new Answer :

This is my request via Java API

```
'SearchRequest{searchType=QUERY_THEN_FETCH, indices=[products], indicesOptions=IndicesOptions[id=38, ignore_unavailable=false, allow_no_indices=true, expand_wildcards_open=true, expand_wildcards_closed=false, allow_aliases_to_multiple_indices=true, forbid_closed_indices=true, ignore_aliases=false], types=[doc], routing='null', preference='null', requestCache=null, scroll=null, maxConcurrentShardRequests=0, batchedReduceSize=512, preFilterShardSize=128, source={"size":50,"query":{"match_phrase":{"code":{"query":"1615","slop":0,"boost":1.0}}}}}
```

' . But am getting response as `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow up: [ElasticSearch - JavaApi searching not happening without (*) in my input query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212683/elasticsearch-javaapi-searching-not-happening-without-in-my-input-query/51214924?noredirect=1#comment89426215_51214924)

Your mapping should look like:

```
PUT products
{
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "custom_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "ngram",
      "char_filter": [
        "html_strip"
      ],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
      ]
    }
  }
}
},
"mappings": {
"doc": {
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "text",
       "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

And you should be using a match_phrase query.

**In Kibana:**

```
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "code": "V"
    }
  }
}
```

will return the result:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "products",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "EoGtdGQBqdof7JidJkM_",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "code": "MS-VMA1615-0D"
        }
      }
    ]
```

But this:

```
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "code": "VK"
    }
  }
}
```

wont:

```
{
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

**Based on your comment:**

Instead of using a Query string:

```
QueryStringQueryBuilder qsQueryBuilder = new QueryStringQueryBuilder(code); 
qsQueryBuilder.defaultField("code");
searchSourceBuilder.query(qsQueryBuilder);
searchSourceBuilder.size(50);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Use a match phrase query:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("code", code);
searchSourceBuilder.query(query);
searchSourceBuilder.size(50);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Comment: If am searching for `1615`.,  am getting these results also `S683616161`, `S611751561` & `S661506173` which is not exactly having `1615`.  Am using `QueryStringQueryBuilder qsQueryBuilder = new QueryStringQueryBuilder(code); `  java API.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I have modified my code as per suggest. But am getting null pointer exception on this line `SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();`

Comment: @Technocrad - I have updated my question with my request,

Comment: Hey, the request is perfectly fine, I have tried it in java as well and it is giving me the expected results. The problem is something else, maybe you need to debug to check.

Comment: If i want to search `code` with multiple fields means. how can i do that ..?

Comment: I have raised separate question for the same . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377176/elasticsearch-matchphrasequery-api-to-search-with-multiple-fields